# How to update or edit profile information

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am making an app that is the AirBnB of cars for a project. I am currently busy with the client profile and I would like to add a feature whereby a user can edit/update their profile. I honestly don't know how.

I am using Ionic 2 and typescript.

This is my Firebase:

[image: Firebase]

Below is my code:

auth.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import firebase from 'firebase';


/*
  Generated class for the AuthProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {

  public fireAuth:firebase.auth.Auth;
  public userProfileRef:firebase.database.Reference;
  public vehicleRef:firebase.database.Reference;
  //public userId= firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.fireAuth = firebase.auth();
    this.userProfileRef = firebase.database().ref('/userProfile');
    //this.userId= firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    //this.vehicleRef = firebase.database().ref('/userProfile/' + userId + '/vehicles/');//linked to firebase node userProfile
    console.log('Hello AuthProvider Provider');
  }



  loginUser(email: '', password: ''): firebase.Promise<any>{
    return this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  viewUser(userId: any){
            var userRef = this.userProfileRef.child(userId);
            return userRef.once('value'); 
}
  /*
  viewCar(carId: any){
    var userId= firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        var userRef = this.vehicleRef.child('/userProfile/' + userId + '/vehicles/' + carId);
        return userRef.once('value'); 
}*/

  signupUser(name: string, surname: string, birthday: any, licenseNum: string, email: string, password: string ): firebase.Promise<any> {
    return this.fireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then( newUser => {
      this.userProfileRef.child(newUser.uid).update({
        name: name,
        surname: surname,
        birthday: birthday,
        licenseNum: licenseNum,
        email: email,
        password: password
      });
    });
  }

  resetPassword(email: string): firebase.Promise<void> {
    return this.fireAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
  }

  logoutUser(): firebase.Promise<void>{
    this.userProfileRef.child(this.fireAuth.currentUser.uid).off();
    return this.fireAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

clientprofile.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title>
      Client Profile
    </ion-title>

  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding id="page6">
  <ion-list id="clientProfile-list2">

    <ion-item color="none" id="clientProfile-list-item4">
      <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img src="assets/img/baHyhhtoTuztiAKn4F4x_download.jpeg" />
      </ion-thumbnail>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item id="clientProfile-input2">
      <ion-label>
        Name
      </ion-label>
      <ion-note item-end>{{ userDisplayName }}</ion-note>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item id="clientProfile-input3">
      <ion-label>
        Surname
      </ion-label>
      <ion-note item-end>{{ userDisplaysName }}</ion-note>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item id="clientProfile-input5">
      <ion-label>
        Birthday
      </ion-label>
      <ion-note item-end>{{ userDisplayBirth }}</ion-note>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item id="clientProfile-input6">
      <ion-label>
        Email
      </ion-label>
      <ion-note item-end>{{ userDisplayEmail }}</ion-note>
    </ion-item>


    <!--<ion-item id="clientProfile-input7">-->
    <!--  <ion-label>-->
    <!--    Password-->
    <!--  </ion-label>-->
    <!--  <ion-input type="text" placeholder=""></ion-input>-->
    <!--</ion-item>-->
  </ion-list>
  <!--<button id="feedback-button10" ion-button color="positive" block on-click="goToFeedback()"> <!--block href-inappbrowser="/signup"-->-->
  <!--   Edit Profile-->
  <!--  </button>-->
  <button id="feedback-button10" ion-button color="positive" block on-click="goToFeedback()"> <!--block href-inappbrowser="/signup"-->
     Feedback
    </button>
</ion-content>
```

and clientprofile.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthProvider } from '../../providers/auth/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { FeedbackPage } from '../feedback/feedback';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-client-profile',
  templateUrl: 'client-profile.html',

})
export class ClientProfilePage {
  private userPhotoUrl:any;
  private userDisplayEmail : any;
  private userDisplaysName : any;
  private userDisplayName : any;
  private userDisplayBirth : any;
  private userDisplayLicense : any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private AuthProvider: AuthProvider) { 

    var myUserid= firebase.auth().currentUser.uid; //current user id
    this.displayUser(myUserid);

  }

  displayUser(theUserId){

    var that = this;

    this.AuthProvider.viewUser(theUserId).then(snapshot => {



       that.userDisplayEmail= snapshot.val().email;
       that.userDisplayName= snapshot.val().name;
       that.userDisplaysName= snapshot.val().surname;
       that.userDisplayBirth= snapshot.val().birthday;
       that.userDisplayLicense= snapshot.val().licenseNum
    })
}

  goToFeedback(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(FeedbackPage);
  }
}
```

I assume that my code would need to go in the auth.ts. And the html should allow for a small edit option on the side of each field

Here is my attempt in the auth.ts:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateProfile({ displayName: "Jane Q. User"}).then(function() {
```

Comment: this really sounds like you want us to just develop an entire feature for you. This isn't what SO is meant to do. It's meant to help you find a solution to a specific problem, not do the work instead of you. Please take some time and read the how to ask a good question guide. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Il add my attempt

Comment: What exactly do you need? Do you need a firebase query to update the existing user data?

Comment: No i want to allow users to click a button on the bottom of their profile that takes them to a page whereby they can edit the fields in their existing profile, such as change name, email. but need sto update in firebase too

Comment: That doesn't sound so hard. Just fetch all the user data from Firebase on click of that button and render that in the form. And then if the user changes any of that data, make an update call to Firebase.

Comment: no clue how to do it. Will have to study

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: How about you stop being so serious about life